# How to achieve functionality of idleBetweenPolls in spring kafka with spring boot(2.1.6 version)

Tags: spring-kafka

I would like to set the polling interval between 2 polls. I know that this can be achieved using spring kafka version- 2.3 above using idleBetweenPolls property setting at container level

But how this feature can be achieved with spring boot version 2.1.6 version of spring kafka ? I could not go higher versions of spring boot.

Help would be greatly appreciated!!

EDIT: Application will consume the messages in batch. So we would like to set the polling interval at 5 min.

Comment: It cannot; and spring-boot 2.1.x spring-kafka 2.2.x are end of life and no longer supported.

Comment: for doc reference they are end of life https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka

Comment: but may i know how  we are controlling polling interval in lower version? what i mean is how to hold the consumer for a certain interval ?

Comment: Even i tried testing with spring boot 2.3.8 version of kafa, but we are unable to consume the message from the azure event hubs.  Thats why we are planning to go lower version.